# Easiest Subversion installer for Windows 7?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I want to try out Subversion on Windows 7.  The repository will be on the same PC I'll be accessing it on (i.e., server and client on same computer)  I read a blog entry that suggested that [VisualSVNServer](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) was the easiest way to install SVN.

Any better suggestions or comments on whether VSVNS is indeed the easiest to install?

Comment: VisualSVNServer was very easy. I use it. I would recommend that you use VisualSVNServer since you do not need to know any command line stuff to use it.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I'd go for Tortoise if it's only a local repository.

Comment: I thought Tortoise was just a GUI client for SVN. Wouldn't you still need to install the SVN server?

Comment: Tortoise can host a local repository just fine (The "Create Repository Here" in the right-click menu is a good starting point ;). If it's a one-man project and you're hosting the repo on your development machine, then it's easily sufficient for what you need.

Comment: Tortoise is juts the GUI for SVN. You would still need a server. VisualSVN does the job.
@Anon Never thought of that. Nice. But, you would not be able to view with your browser.

Comment: Tortoise's repository browser is sufficient for most things you'd want to do for a one-man project. If it gets too big then yes, you'd want to move to a dedicated server software - but if it's just you or you're just trying out SVN, then Tortoise is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

I use VisualSVN Server for the server and TortoiseSVN as a shell client. The combo works like a charm and allows me both local and remote access. The VsualSVN server setup is incredibly easy; the only caveat is that every once in a while when upgrading to newer version, I lose the custom security on my repos and have to set it again.

Answer (score 1):

To install the Subversion server, get it from [here](http://www.open.collab.net/products/subversion/).